# Non blocking postback C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nonblocking

I'm working on a ASP.NEW web application which calls a api on selecting an item to verify information.

The **selectItem_Command()** is called on selecting the item, which **shows a modal** with the item details, and **starts the api call**. The API call takes around **4 seconds to complete** on average.

**This is what I want:**
1. Finish the postback after CallAPI(); so that the modal is shown ( a message will be shown in the modal saying we're verifying details).

2. After the API responds back update details in the modal.

**My Problem is this:**
 The Execution is blocked at CallAPI() as the compiler is waiting until the api sends data even though I've marked the CallAPI() function async.

As a result the modal isn't shown until the entire api operation is completed.

Is There a way to finish the postback after CallAPI() and after the API sends data back to cause a second postback to the modal to update some fields in it?.

`

```
protected void selectItem_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  ShowModal();
  CallAPI();
}

private async void CallAPI()
{
  //do Some stuff
  Update something on the Modal();

}
```

`

Comment: `CallAPI` should return a `Task` and `selectItem_Command` should be marked `async void` and `await` `CallAPI`.

Comment: You can call the api using a `Task.Run`.

Comment: I usually put the call to the api in a backgroundworker.

Comment: don't use Task.Run or BackgroundWorker in asp.net! Sorry guys, but that is bad advice and wouldn't solve the problem anyway. What you want lends itself to ajax techniques rather than postbacks. You can sort of fake it by popping the modal with javascript before posting, but you'll need to recreate it on postback.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, that's what I figured too. So this is what I did.
1. On button click show the modal using jQuery.
2. Start the postback where the api is called.
3. After completion of api call, update the contents inside the modal using Ajax UpdatePanel inside the modal. 

Kaboom, problem solved. Thanks.